# Call REST URL Using Camel

Tags: java, xml, rest, apache-camel

I need to call my local rest service from camel.

When i called URL from browser i got a response.

for Example

http://localhost:8081/buzzor/secure/buzzorapp/getAvailableLanguages

I got a result back:

```
 [
    {
        "name": "English",
        "value": "en"
    },
    {
        "name": "मराठी",
        "value": "mr"
    },
    {
        "name": "ગુજરાતી",
        "value": "gu"
    },
    {
        "name": "தமிழ்",
        "value": "ta"
    },
    {
        "name": "हिन्दी",
        "value": "hi"
    },
    {
        "name": "Français",
        "value": "fr"
    },
    {
        "name": "తెలుగు",
        "value": "te"
    }
]
```

now same REST URL i need to call from Camel, For this i have create one Route.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="false">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start" />
        <to uri="http://localhost:8081/buzzor/secure/buzzorapp/getAvailableLanguages" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

after doing this if i run the project URL not getting called. Please tell me at which place i have made mistake. on a console site i only get output:

```
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ CXF-Sample <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1:run (default-cli) @ CXF-Sample ---
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.spring.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Comment: From the error it seems its not an issue with the camel but the `slf4j jar` file that you've included in your build path. please verify the version or use `slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar` or 1.6+

Comment: Agree but why the service/URL is not getting called?

Comment: Aren't you sending to and not calling from the REST service, what happens if you change `to` and `from` in your route-declaration?

Comment: Try to add a camel log component into your camel route and see if you are getting a response from the Rest Service call, if you're not getting a response you'll need to set Header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    try {
        ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
        context.start();

        Exchange exchange = template
                .request(
                        "http://localhost:8081/buzzor/secure/buzzorapp/getAvailableLanguages",
                        new Processor() {
                            public void process(Exchange exchange)
                                    throws Exception {
                            }
                        });

        if (null != exchange) {
            Message out = exchange.getOut();
            System.out.println(out.getBody().toString());
            int responseCode = out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE,
                    Integer.class);
            System.out.println("Response: " + String.valueOf(responseCode));
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
        context.stop();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
    }

    System.out.println("DONE!!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using a `direct` endpoint as a consumer. That means that you will need to send an exchange to `direct:start` in order to trigger the http get.

What about using a timer that runs once?

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="false">
  <route>
    <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
    <to uri="http://localhost:8081/buzzor/secure/buzzorapp/getAvailableLanguages" />
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

This route will run and call the http endpoint once.

Comment: You have saved me. I was looking for a configuration to read JSON from rest API every day. And I did not found how to it.